# MKMapView load warning: More than xxx names on road (xxxxxxx). Data is probably bad. Please open a radar

Tags: ios, mkmapview, zooming, warnings

When I zoom mapView in app,xcode received many similar warnings **"More than xxx names on road (xxxxxxx). Data is probably bad. Please open a radar"**,how to solve this problem？

Edit:

```
self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
self.mapView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.mapView];
```

Just use the codes to create a map, when run app and enlarge map, xcode received many similar warnings, But app can worked well.